# 405 in flask from GET to POST to GET again

Tags: python, flask

I start at `home.html`, click an item link to go to `item.html`. In `item.html` I click the delete button, submitting the delete form, the delete endpoint then tries to redirect back to `home.html`. This is when the 405 occurs.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2022 15:12:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2022 15:12:59] "GET /item/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2022 15:13:00] "POST /item/1/delete HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2022 15:13:00] "submit=Delete+itemGET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
pretending to delete 1
```

The problem is in the WTForm, compare:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('delete_item', item_id=item_id) }}">     
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">     
   {{ delete_item_form.submit() }} 
</form>
```

The WTForm submit causes the problem, the normal input does not.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "unguessable"


class DeleteAnItemForm(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField("Delete item")


@app.route("/item/<int:item_id>/delete", methods=["POST"])
def delete_item(item_id):
    print(f"pretending to delete {item_id}")
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


@app.route("/item/<int:item_id>")
def item(item_id):
    delete_item_form = DeleteAnItemForm()
    return render_template('item.html', item_id=item_id, delete_item_form=delete_item_form)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

`home.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>HOME</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('item', item_id=1) }}">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('item', item_id=2) }}">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('item', item_id=3) }}">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('item', item_id=4) }}">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('item', item_id=5) }}">5</a></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

`item.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Viewing item {{ item_id }}</p>

<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('delete_item', item_id=item_id) }}">
    {{ delete_item_form.submit(class="btn btn-danger") }}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have found out what is causing the crash, it doenst make any sense:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('delete_item', item_id=item_id) }}">
    <div>
        works
        <input type="submit" value="This works">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
        Both crash
        {{ delete_item_form.submit() }}
        <input id="submit" name="crashes" type="submit" value="Also crashes">
    </div>
</form>
```

Whenever the input field has a "name" attribute the crash occurs, this is done automatically by WTForms. Any ideas why?

Comment: I tried to copy paste the provided code and I can't reproduce the error. Home  (click link) > Item (click delete) > Delete_Item (redirect to home) > Home ✓

Comment: Mostly these errors are due to the code editor dependency libraries. Are you using Jupyter notebook/Anaconda or simple Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using pycharm. Ive also tried it outside of pycharm and I get the same  error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similiar problem the past few hours and found [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2380). Essentially, the problem seems to come down to Flask's development server due to enabling keep-alive behavior in 2.1.

Using a production ready server (such as waitress), wouldn't cause the problem.

The easiest way to fix it in my case was to downgrade Werkzeuge to 2.0.3. Alternatively, always consuming the data should help as well.

Comment: Great thanks, that fixed it. I changed the version of Werkzeuge to 2.0.3 as you say and it now works. Really strange, but good to know thanks alot !!! The problem was when the submit input had a "name" attribute, something that WTForms does automatically.

Comment: And also as you say just consuming the values:     ```print(request.form.values())                # consuming the values.''' also fixes it if using the latest version of Werkzeuge